# Problem for dynamic memory allocation in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

while i am trying to solve a hackerrank problem,i had a problem in my mind.My problem is i want to allocate some memories with pointers and i made this with two ways,but one of them resulted with the problem.Other one has no problem.

**Hackerrank problem is here 1.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nz5H.png)

**Hackerrank problem is here 2.**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk1AD.png)

**Hackerrank problem is here 3.**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKDGG.png)

**This code worked with no problem.**

```
int x,y,z;
cin>>x>>y;
int *arr[x];
for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
    int z;
    cin>>z;
    arr[i] = new int[z];
    for(int j=0;j<z;j++){
        cin >> arr[i][j]; 
    }
    
}
int *arr2[y];
for(int k=0;k<y;k++){
    arr2[k] = new int[2];
    for(int tt=0;tt<2;tt++){
        cin >> arr2[k][tt];
    }
    
}
for(int i = 0;i<y;i++){
    
        cout<<arr[arr2[i][0]][arr2[i][1]]<<endl;
    
}
```

**My question is here.**

**what is the problemlem for making a definition of  int *arr = new int[x]; rather than *arr[x] I want to make a new allocation with pointer.Is both of them aren't same ? I didn't understand. **
**If a make a definition of int *arr = new int[x]; then the problem is arr[i] = new int[z];**

```
int x,y,z;
cin>>x>>y;
int *arr = new int[x];  **<-- **
for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
    int z;
    cin>>z;
    arr[i] = new int[z];   **<-- problem**
    for(int j=0;j<z;j++){
        cin >> *arr[i][j]; 
    }
    
}
int *arr2 = new int[y];
for(int k=0;k<y;k++){
    arr2[k] = new int[2];
    for(int tt=0;tt<2;tt++){
        cin >> *arr2[k][tt];
    }
    
}
for(int i = 0;i<y;i++){
    
        cout<<*arr[*arr2[i][0]][*arr2[i][1]]<<endl;
    
}


  
return 0;
```

Comment: `int* arr[x]` is an array of pointers to `int`, and `arr[y]` is a pointer to `int`. `int* arr` is one pointer to `int`, and `arr[y]` is one `int`.

Comment: fwiw, what you really should be doing is using `std::vector`. Most problems will be gone

Comment: `int *arr = new int[x];` should be `int** arr = new int*[x];`

Comment: I believe this answer should help: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/936702/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936702/487892) see the Otherwise part!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make a matrix (2-dimensional array) from an array. You should write like that:

```cpp
int **matrix = new int*[x]; //pay attention to number of asterisks
for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
{
  matrix[i] = new int[z];
}
```

`int *arr[x]` is similar to `int **matrix = new int*[x]`. It creates an array of `x` arrays with undefined size.

P.S: using pointers in C++ is considered a bad practice. You should use `std::vector` instead. That's an example:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(x);
for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
{
  matrix[i] = std::vector<int>(z);
}
```

P.P.S: don't forget to `#include <vector>`.

Comment: This became so helpful for me and i understood a lot with the help of you.Thank you so much :D

Comment: I'm glad to help you!

Comment: However,i didn't understand vectors.In which situations should i use vectors instead of using pointers in memory allocation ? Why should i use vectors?

Comment: `std::vector` is nothing more than a dynamically allocated array. In C++ you almost never use raw pointers for the purposes of creating a collection of data. `std::vector` is safer (don't need to free memory by yourself) and more convenient (you are able to use some interesting premade stuff with it in C++).

Comment: Thanks a lot again,have a nice day!

Comment: I have some litte problem again,can you explain for me ? Why can't i use  cin >> *arr2[k][tt];   (* in front of arr2[k] or others like this example). I had one queston. If i don't use * , is it become address ? if i don't use * , won't i change its addresses ? After define a pointer can't i use *ptr instead ptr in order to assign a value to it ?

Comment: Could you please provide some more context?

Comment: Actually more context is in the post question. I made a problem while solving it . (I used * some areas in the question if you look.) And i made a compile error.

Comment: `cin >> *arr[i][j];` is wrong because `arr[i][j]` is an `int` not a pointer. You want `arr[i][j]` instead.

Comment: No, it's not an addres. To understand it you need to know what `array[i]` really means. `int *array` is a pointer to a memory location with a size of `int` (usually 4 bytes). And `array[i]` is an **element at address** of `array + i*sizeof(int)`.